# If $p_0$ is a strict local maximum of $g$, then it is a center of the Hamiltonian System $p'=H_g(p)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, gradient-flows, hamilton-equations

This is supposed to be an ordinary differential equations class exercise:

> Let $g\in \scr{C}^2(\Bbb{R}^2;\Bbb{R})$ and consider
>   $$H_g(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_yg(x,y)\\ -\partial_xg(x,y)\end{pmatrix}.$$
>
> Show that, if $g$ admits a strict local maximum point (non-degenerated) at $p_0=(x_0,y_0)$ then near to $p_0$ there are infinitely many periodic orbits of the o.d.e. $p'(s)=H_g(p(s))$

I know facts like:

- the level curves of $g$ are integral curves of the o.d.e. $p'(s)=H_g(p(s))$;
- $\langle \nabla g,H_g\rangle=0$;
- basic facts about $\nabla g$, etc;
- basic facts about o.d.e.'s like existence and uniqueness theorem, o.d.e.'s systems, etc.

Furthermore, I can geometrically visualize that, if $p_0$ is a point of maximum isolated, then "around it", there is infinitely many closed level curves (imagine the surface given by the graph of $g$). But I don't have any idea of how to prove it formally...

I'm really stuck!

Comment: Just how much rigorous math do you know?  For example, can we quote the implicit function theorem?  (I would probably need this to show that the level curves of $g$ close to $(x_0,y_0)$ can be parameterized as a curve.)

Comment: Yes, we can use it, @StephenMontgomery-Smith

Comment: Also, before trying something more complicated, have you tried using polar coordinates around $ (x_0,y_0)$?  Show that in a small neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ that $\dot\theta>0$, and that for any $\theta$ there is a unique $r$ for any given energy level.